# Java extract date from a list of files using lastindexof

Tags: java

I have a bunch of files with naming convetions like this:

```
Call_Report_Jan_15_2015_0804AM.csv
Facility_Protection_Group_Report_Jan_15_2015_0800AM.csv
Node_Report_Jan_15_2015_0800AM.csv
Network_Element_Report_Jan_15_2015_0800AM.csv
```

From what I notice, the date that I need is always after the . extension name. I'm trying to use lasindexof but can't seem to figure it out

```
String fileDate = file.substring(0,file..lastIndexOf(".", 0));
```

I keep getting an error below even if I change the 0 to -1:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
at com.extract.populateConfigDate(extract.java:183)
at com.extract.connectFTPTellabs(extract.java:103)
at com.extract.<init>(extract.java:78)
at com.Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

Anyone has an idea if it can be done or do i need to use regex?

EDIT: file = name of the csv file

Comment: What is `file`? Try using `file.substring(0, file.lastIndexOf("."))` instead

Comment: `String file = "Network_Element_Report_Jan_15_2015_0800AM.csv";
        int index = file.lastIndexOf(".");
        String fileDate = file.substring(index-18, index);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the JavaDocs for [`String#lastIndexOf(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,%20int))

> Returns the index within this string of the last occurrence of the specified substring, searching backward starting at the specified index.

This means that method is starting at position `0` and trying to move backwards from there

Try using something like `file.substring(0, file.lastIndexOf("."))` or `file.substring(0, file.lastIndexOf(".", file.length()))` instead

This will strip of the extension.  Next you will need to strip of the file name to get to the date.

Now, you could use a regular expression instead, be warned though, my regular expression is pretty basic, however, something like...

```
String file = "Call_Report_Jan_15_2015_0804AM.csv";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(file);
if (matcher.find()) {
    int startIndex = matcher.start();
    int endIndex = matcher.end();
    String group = matcher.group();
    System.out.println(group);
}
```

Outputs

```
Jan_15_2015_0804AM
```